# Can you create variables in a loop? C#

Tags: c#, loops, variable-declaration

In C#, is it possible to declare variables in a loop? I have an array of names, and I want them all to be variables. Is there a way to create them? something like

```
string[] nameArray{ name, othername, anothername };

foreach ( var file in nameArray ) {
    data 'file' = new data();
}
```

Comment: You can declare variables within a loop, but I think what you're looking for in this case is an array. The entries within an array are unnamed, but the array itself is named and individual entries are referred to by index.

Comment: you can create variable like this

foreach ( var file in nameArray )
{
//here i am creating var1 variable
  data var1= new data();
}

Comment: It is NOT possible. Why do you want to have something like this?

Comment: I am reading the names from a directory, and want to declare the file names as variables

Comment: You __could__ declare and create variables inside a loop like at any other place but each would a) be recreated on each iteration and b) be lost when the loop goes out of scope. Use a dictionary as Thomas suggests!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare variables "dynamically" like this, variable names must be known statically at compile time. However you can achieve a similar result by using a `Dictionary`:

```
string[] nameArray = { "name", "othername", "anothername" };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, data>();
foreach ( var file in nameArray )
{
    dict[file] = new data();
}
```

Comment: How would you recall data?

Comment: `Console.Write(dict["name"]);`